# Finding an element of Gelfand triple with a designated time derivative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, examples, schwartz-distributions

Let $V$ be a real separable Banach space and $H$ be a real separable Hilbert space such that
\begin{equation}
V \subset H \subset V'
\end{equation}
where $V'$ is the dual of $V$ and the inclusions are continuous with dense ranges.

Also, let $1<q \leq p<\infty$ be such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and consider an arbitrary element $\phi \in L^{q}\bigl(0,1 ; V'\bigr)$.

My question: Can we always find some $\Phi \in L^{p}\bigl(0,1 ;V\bigr)$ such that $\partial_t \Phi = \phi$?

Here, $\partial_t\Phi$ is defined as a continuous linear operator from $\mathcal{D}$ into $V'$ with the formula
\begin{equation}
\partial_t\Phi(f):=-\int_0^1  \Phi(t) f'(t)dt 
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{D}$ is the Fréchet space of real-valued, compactly supported smooth functions on $[0,1]$ and $V'$ is equipped with the weak$^*$ topology.

I am pretty sure that we can always find such $\Phi$ but cannot explicitly construct one myself. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What if $\phi(t) = y$ is a constant that is in $V' \setminus V$?  Then it seems like the only candidate for $\Phi$ is $\Phi(t) = ty$ which is not $V$-valued at all.